# Sapi sound output issue

Tags: visual-studio, text-to-speech, sapi

While making a tts engine compatible with Microsoft SAPI 5.3 I encountered a strange issue. I use HTS_engine as the underlying engine that produce the sound. After my engine received the synthesis request from sapi and handled it, I retrieved a buffer of audio data. Then according to the sample provided by Microsoft I write the data to SAPI app through ISpTTSEngineSite::write(). However, the result is so poor that it is reduced to just sound, no longer voice. When I use the buffer of audio to write to a wav file, it is completely fine. So What did I do wrong here?

```
fwrite(audio, sizeof(char), len, outfile); //completely fine
fclose(outfile);
hr = pOutputSite->Write(audio, len, &actual_len); //terrible sound
m_ullAudioOff += len;
```

I did read carefully on the [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717037(v=vs.85).aspx) and the sample code but can't figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out the problem. SAPI supports a lot of sound formats but my engine only provide the 44khz mono 16 bit sound. Therefore when sapi try to convert my data into the default 11khz mono 16 bit the sound got distorted. I just need to get it to the right format and it solved.